# Trying to use bash on Windows and got no installed distributions message

Tags: linux, windows, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use **bash** on **Windows 10**, but I'm getting this message when tried to run bash:

> Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
>   Distributions can be installed by visiting the Windows Store:
>   https://aka.ms/wslstore Press any key to continue...

When I go to that url which opens the **Windows Store** app, there no sign of any **Linux** distribution there.

My windows version is(as in my right bottom corner of the screen):

> Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview. Evaluation copy.Build
>   16215.rs_prerelease.170603-1840

I follow the instructions in this guide [Installation Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide) and also was watching this video [Editing code and files on Windows Subsystem for Linux on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfRo63afjtM&feature=em-uploademail) from Scott Hanselman, but they didn't get the message of no installed distribution.

Any Help?

Comment: Cygwin could be alternative, a [Linux/Unix]-like environment for Windows: https://cygwin.com/  ... you can get bash, and many other things, from this interface.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww is not a direct development question, but I need this bash on windows to test some new stuff I am trying with .net core, and all the new stuff in the new Microsoft tech stack, also this is related to programming because a common Windows user does not need this I think.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2212

Comment: I read this article today [Ubuntu is now available for download on the Windows Store](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/10/15949096/ubuntu-windows-10-store-linux-distro-sandbox-available-now), when open the store shows **Ubuntu** as not installed app though

Comment: WARNING: Do not run `lxrun /install` if this is occurs after using WSL for some time. It will wipe your entire linux filesystem. Found out the hard way.

Comment: See [Windows Subsystem for Linux Installation Guide for Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)

Comment: I resolved using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63858461/windows-subsystem-for-linux-has-no-installed-distributions-even-i-installed-ub/63858800#63858800

Comment: Check the user account of the powershell session. It seems that Administrator account can't detect WSL while the normal account where you installed the WSL can.

Comment: Git Bash runs fine for me if I run the app directly, so I don't like all these answers that involve installing something. I know I already have everything I need installed, the command only fails from the command line

Answer (score 173, accepted):

When the Windows Store opened, there was no Distro to choose, then I found this command `lxrun /install` and worked for me as well.

You will get something like this as an output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lxrun /install
Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

This will install Ubuntu on Windows, distributed by Canonical and licensed under its terms available here:
https://aka.ms/uowterms

Type "y" to continue: y
Downloading from the Microsoft Store... 100%
Extracting filesystem, this will take a few minutes...
Would you like to set the Ubuntu locale to match the Windows locale (en-FI)?
The default locale is en_US.
Type "y" to continue: y
Please create a default UNIX user account. The username does not need to match your Windows username.
For more information visit: https://aka.ms/wslusers
Enter new UNIX username: <you type your login here>
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
Installation successful!
Documentation is available at:  https://aka.ms/wsldocs
```

Comment: Never see a Distro to choose in the Windows Store, but the lxrun/install command worked fine

Comment: Here is a print screen of the process after running lxrun/install [Installing Bash on Windows](http://i.imgur.com/rjQ2iNe.png)

Comment: When running lxrun the following warning shows up and that is why I downvoted: > Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.

Comment: thank you.. this is the only way for me. I am from Indonesia. https://imgur.com/a/HLmqoev

Comment: In case you're wondering, this command needs to be run on command prompt.

Comment: Windows store is not available on company's machine. Can I not install ubuntu distro anyhow? I have enabled the Windows subsystem for linux already, but not able to install  any distribution.

Comment: @hsingh - you can [install WSL manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), i.e. without the Windows Store

Comment: How much time it will take? it is stucked at "Extracting filesystem..."

Comment: lxrun doesn't seem to exist on Windows 2019

Comment: `lxrun` is replaced by `wsl`

Comment: now you have to type: "wsl --install -d Ubuntu"

Answer (score 26):

I'm getting a similar bug after trying to uninstall and reinstall.

For me I had to open a cmd prompt as administrator and run `lxrun /install`

Comment: When running lxrun the following warning shows up and that is why I downvoted: > Warning: lxrun.exe is only used to configure the legacy Windows Subsystem for Linux distribution.

Comment: Well it has been a year @RandallFlagg =) , now that distributions are handled in the windows store, the entire question is invalid.

Answer (score 25):

I get this when I have recently rebooted. If I wait 5 minutes, the problem fixes itself !

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer, I've been using the Windows Subsystem for Linux for over a year and today when I had just powered on my laptop it was showing up with this error for the first time for me and I thought I was going to have to run the `lxrun` command from the first answer or find something to install to fix it, but upon seeing this answer, I decided just to wait, and you were right, it did start working after a few minutes.

Comment: Oh wow, you are right! I rebooted the first time since I installed WSL and I get this error and freak out. So weird...

Comment: This is relevant in case you already installed linux distribution from store.

Comment: this works. this is beyond frustrating. turned off computer, forgot to commit to git, then waited for restart...and now sitting here. any idea why it takes _minutes_?!

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens but rather than waiting 5 minutes restarting the LxssManager service works for me.

Answer (score 21):

The top answers written for this question are more than enough. I just had trouble following them because `lxrun` command has been depreceated, so I get the error

> 'lxrun' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

when I try to run this command with cmd.

It has been replaced with `wsl` command. You can get more info on this issue here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/425

When you run `wsl /install`, there is a chance you may still get the error that you had earlier posted in your question. In that case, simply go to the link https://aka.ms/wslstore as you had gone earlier. If you don't see anything coming up, simply search for Ubuntu and install the same. (If you search with the term `wsl` though, you will get to see other Linux flavors too and then you can download any of your choice)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. The command lxrun /install didn't work, but wsl /install worked

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

Answer (score 17):

It seems that the link given in the command doesn't work. Here's the actual link to the microsoft store for Ubuntu.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?rtc=1

Comment: This works if searching for Linux on the store doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 8):

If you have any problems with running `lxrun /install` (for example on ltsb Windows version) try manual mode.

First, go to the folder with downloaded `.appx` file and run following commands (change filename if needed):

```
Rename-Item ~/Ubuntu.appx ~/Ubuntu.zip
Expand-Archive ~/Ubuntu.zip ~/Ubuntu
```

After finishing cd into new folder and run `ubuntu.exe` file. That's it.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me on Server 2019 build 1809

Comment: Amazing, this totally worked for us too.

Comment: I get Operation Failed. False  v4.0.30319     C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\WindowsBase.dll

Answer (score 7):

You have to go to https://aka.ms/wslstore this link and download ubuntu on windows. After that you can use bash on windows.

Comment: The link doesn't work for all countries it seems.  Why on earth would they put region locking there?

Comment: This doesn't work. It opens the store and says something is wrong, no distros are showing. Oddly, they're accessible from search, but there's no list of the WSL distros

Comment: @Zoe I think that must be on your end because, ironically enough I just did that very step successfully just 55 minutes after you commented. Maybe try again! :)

Comment: @joshmcode it's been 19 hours, still doesn't work. Still the same "Please wait a little while, and try again". If 19 hours doesn't fix it, there's no point in trying. As mentioned in the first comment on this question, this may be a regional issue, in which case waiting won't fix anything.

Comment: I see. Sorry! :( I hope you're able to figure a workaround out soon.

Comment: You probably running Windows LTSC (missing Windows Store). The url https://aka.ms/wslstore gives me a blank screen too but a direct download link like https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804 is available.

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who is getting

```
'lxrun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

or

```
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore
```

Open microsoft store, install 'Ubuntu' then open the app. This will install ubuntu and later you can use `wsl` command since `lxrun` is deprecated

Answer (score 5):

If you get this error after installing a distribution using the windows store, and WSL was working previously, you may need to make sure that the LxssManager service is running, since it often stops after a Windows update or a reboot.

Go to services.msc, and search for `LxssManager` and start it; if it is running already, restart it.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to add or remove programs
2. Install Windows subsystem for Linux
3. Go to https://aka.ms/wslstore, which will take you to the Microsoft Store
4. Select and install a Linux distribution

Answer (score 2):

```
lxrun /install
```

Works on a Administrator Command Prompt for Windows 10 Professional, Version 1803 Build 17134.165

This installs GNU/Linux by default whereas there is an option to select between:

- Ubuntu
- openSUSE Leap 42
- SUSE Linux Enterprise
- Debian GNU/Linux
- Kali Linux

If the given link (https://aka.ms/wslstore) works, it openes the windows store for me with an error saying something is wrong on their side and to try again later.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually easier to solve this problem that other solutions listed here. If you run `wslconfig /l` and if the output is:

`Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
 Ubuntu (Default)`

Just run `wslconfig /s Ubuntu` to set Ubuntu as default again. It should start working now.

Edit:

I've also found that if this problem occurs on a fresh boot, then you just wait for a few minutes (10 minutes max) and this error automatically disappears.

Edit 2:
I've also found that this error is sometimes also due to the corresponding service not running. Run CMD as administrator and run

`net start LxssManager`

Answer (score 2):

For running bash on windows ubuntu is required to be installed.

As you've already added bash from programs and features, now you need to install Ubuntu. Contrary to what is seen in most of the installation guides on web, it does not gets installed by running 'bash.exe'.

You can simply go to Microsoft store in search for 'Bash' or 'Ubuntu'and install Ubuntu 18 LTS from there.

After installation you'll be able to use the terminal and all its commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. But when you go to the windows store you can search for ubuntu and then install the ubuntu app and it works. I think most of the tutorials on the net are from the beta version and have afterwards never been updated.

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/07/11/windows-10-loves-ubuntu-loveislove/

Note: This is also old. You do not need to be on the insider builds. I'm not and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Run the `bash` command in [git bash windows](https://gitforwindows.org/). It worked !!

Comment: Not to be marked as the correct answer, but definitely useful in a hurry. Thanks!

Comment: If the PATH isnt set up right, and trying to run bash from CMD or elsewhere, the WSL fake "bash" can still be invoked and tries to install via WSL.

To get around that `cp /c/path/to/bin/bash.exe /c/Windows/System32/bash.exe` - No more WSL.

Comment: What does this mean? I thought the `bash` command starts Bash. Why would you want to run it from Bash?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#downloading-distros

1. https://aka.ms/wsl-ubuntu-1804
2. manually install it or run *Add-AppxPackage.\.appx* from PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

The link to the store appears to have a region lock in it, resulting in errors for many visitors.

However there are different Ubuntu distributions to be downloaded. See image below, image is however in Dutch but it will show results.

So pick a version you desire and it will result in a working bash.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer to the question query is: The user exists with Ubuntu already installed. But WSL command does not find anything in CMD.exe "Command Line" "System does not find distribution."

You need to start the below WSL command from Windows Start Menu. And then the old Linux System will show up on WSL in the command line as found.

If this doesn't work for you? Just start up PowerShell with Administrator and:

```
WSL --help
WSL "only this command, will start the Linux default distro selected"
```

[image: Run the WSL]

You can then start up using this command with CMD.exe Administrator in Windows:

```
lxrunoffline l "This will now list all your distros"
```

With an option to remove old distros copied to Windows folders are with perhaps Ubuntu18.04 such way that you will have to use Linux to remove older folders, do not try to copy or edit files in a distro with Windows Apps. You risk integrity problems as well as many errors followed by huge processing time. Use folder /mnt to find your drive with Linux and use commands there to further finish your work as perhaps copying the home directory into a new distro.

My solution to move "not copy" my distro then was: "to give space for C:"

```
lxrunoffline m -n Ubuntu-18.04 -d d:\wslinstalled\Ubuntu-18.04 "remember folder names"
```

"Remember folder name such as Ubuntu-18.04 for a specific movement. Unless you will overwrite everything on that folder name with also the lxrunoffline files and you risk losing older copies if you use one folder name. You might end up with a strange name to your project if you just use one directory."

Lxrunoffline has several other commands if you need help just run:

```
lxrunoffline
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, New Linux distributions are available for Windows 10 as well as Windows 11 like Kali Linux and Ubuntu. Both available from Microsoft Store. Someone watching this question now can visit Microsoft Store to Download them..

Answer (score 0):

like [beginner_ said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381772) in his answer you need to go to the store and look for the distros you want to install.
Please see the following [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/05/11/new-distros-coming-to-bashwsl-via-windows-store/) to understand what has changed and what you can excpect or what distros you can look for(the list is outdated so just try to find an updated list or just try your luck).

I am running on my machine ***without*** the developer mode **Ubuntu, OpenSuse** and **Kali**.

Answer (score 0):

Access to Microsoft Store is blocked by my company. For me following worked in PowerShell (admin) -

```
lxrun /install
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to cmd, and then run the following command:
    `lxrun /install`

Answer (score 0):

Typing `lxrun /install` in elevated command prompt works....

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the error "WSL 2 installation is incomplete",

**Execute the following steps:**

1. ***wsl --install -d Ubuntu*** ## lxrun is no more, its now replaced with wsl,
   [image: Refer here for samples].
2. ***wsl***

[image: Refer here for samples].

Answer (score 0):

the following command can be used for the [image: Ubunto installation on windows from cmd]installation of Ubunto

wsl --list --online

official link: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#3-download-ubuntu

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 Nov, Windows 11, none of the above options worked. Installing git bash worked in running .sh files but that didnt solve the underlying problem I had (wanted to compile cpp files) I had to move to Cygwin.